# proxy server which can handle both http and https requests - java

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

i am here looking for resources or sample code for proxy server which can handle both http and https requests written in java. i searched google and found lot of data on how to handle http requests but not https.

Comment: What is the use case? Stephen C provides the correct answer to a generic question. Are you perhaps talking about a need for SSL off-loading? Situations where your webserver technology does not support encryption?

Comment: Are you after a proxy server that you'll be able to configure in most browsers (what I'd call a "normal" HTTP/HTTPS proxy), or something that's able to look into the HTTPS requests too (what I'd call a "MITM proxy"), which would require the browser to allow itself to be fooled into trusting its certificates?

Answer (score 2):

A proxy cannot handle HTTPS and still provide end to end security.  It is not possible using SSL/TLS which is what HTTPS is built on.

And a proxy that doesn't provide end-to-end security only has limited utility.  So I'm not surprised you can't find an existing implementation.

Comment: It depends on what the question is about: whether it about behaving as a "MITM proxy" which would look into the request or a normal HTTPS proxy (which doesn't, and keeps end-to-end security). Both exist.

Comment: Well I always understood a "normal" proxy to be one that would / could do things like caching and filtering.  In order to do that, the proxy has to be a man-in-the-middle because it has to look at the requests and responses to implement that functionality.

Comment: I'd call "normal" the behaviour of an HTTP(S) proxy as used by all major browsers when you configure them to do so. If you configure a "normal" HTTP proxy server in Firefox or IE (for example), it will make a plain HTTP connection to the proxy for `https://` URIs and use the `CONNECT` verb to connect to the hostname and port in the URI. Despite never being finalized as far as I know, this is the spec that has been used by user agents for years when making an `https://` connection via an HTTP proxy: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want a normal HTTPS proxy here, that is a proxy that will not look into the request but merely relay all the traffic to the actual HTTPS server after the user-agent has used the HTTP `CONNECT` method. This is how HTTP proxy servers are normally used for HTTPS requests by browsers.

I haven't tried, but you could look at Jetty and [its `ConnectHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ConnectHandler.html).